# While loop not stoping with random number

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to generate random number between 0 and 10, but loop is not stops when it came to 10

```js
function testNumber () {
    let i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1)
    
    while (i < 10) {
        setInterval(() => {
            document.write("Random number: " + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1)
        )},1000)
               
        return i;
            
    }
    
}
    
function test() {
    testNumber();
}
```

Comment: `i < 10` is always going to be either `true` or `false` depending on the result of the `Math.random`. You never update `i`, so either the loop will run forever or will never run. Not sure what you want, but that's what's currently happening

Comment: try to show random number on display with random number :)

Comment: That's not how `setInterval` works. It's not a sleep function, it creates a loop where the iterations are separated by whatever length of time you give it. On top of that, you're not clearing it, so even if your `while` loop did end, the intervals would still be running and still be generating new numbers. Either use `setTimeout` or get rid of your `while` loop and contain everything inside of `setInterval`.

Comment: You can get a random number in a certain interval without using any loop. Just specify what numbers are acceptable for you and which aren't? 0? 1? 9? 10? 11?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to generate 10 different random nubmers, or stop generating random numbers when you get 10, or even somethig else?

Comment: @Jovana stop generating random numbers when you get 10,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if I did, you want to keep generating random numbers less or equal to 10, until you get 10 and show them in HTML. This is the solution for that:

HTML:

```
<div class="num"> </div>
```

JS:

```
const num = document.querySelector('.num');

function testNumber () {
   let i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)

    while (i !== 10) {
       num.innerHTML = `${num.innerHTML}Random number: ${i}<br>`
       i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "stop generating random numbers when you get 10", you'll probably want something like this:

```
function testNumber() {

    let counter = 0

    while (counter < 10) {
        setInterval(() => {
            document.write("Random number: " + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 11))
            )},1000)
           
             counter++;
    }
}

testNumber();
```

Your loop condition is currently your random number, that's why it will run until the number is 10 by chance. You need to initialize a separate counter variable which gets incremented in each iteration of your loop.

Also your current calculation `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1` would only return numbers from 1 to 10 (excluding 0).

And read about the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function. I'm not sure if that's what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: This one is not stopping...

Answer (score -4):

I think you never change i in loop.
this works:

```
function testNumber () {
    let i=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1)
    const interval=
        setInterval( () => {
            i=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1)
            document.write("Random number: " +i.toString())
            if(i==10) clearInterval(interval)},1000)
}

function test () {
    testNumber()
}
test()
```

clearInterval(interval) allows you to exit interval.